# Overleaf: Is it possible to copy and paste one or multiple files(folders, tex, images....) in overleaf project?

Tags: pdftex, xetex, overleaf, copy-paste, overleaf-toolkit

I am trying to copy many tex. files from one folder to another (tex. files will have same name but a little different content which I would change after copy/paste) at a same project but nothing happens. When I hold "alt" on keyboard to move and copy that file to another folder, it does not working.

Have somebody experience with this?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

I think the only way is to download the project to your local. Then right-click the folder you want to paste and click upload. Then choose all the files from your local. Thats it.